# How to disable trash for remote filesystems in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, gvfs

Is there a way to tell Nautilus (or gvfs) to avoid using the Trash when deleting files on remote filesystems?

Before Nautilus 2.5.0 there was a `filesystem-attributes.xml` that had a "trash" flag, but it was removed with the migration to gnome-vfs